# R Subplot order all plots by one

Tags: r, plotly, subplot

I have 4 plots merged together by subplot function as below. In the first plot in layout I am using `categoryorder = "total descending"` to sort the x axis by y value descending and it works perfectly when I plot it solely. When I include it in the subpplot function and share the axis with the rest of the plots (`shareX = TRUE`) it reverts back to ordering the data alphabetically for all the plots.

Is there any way to have it ordered by the first plot values?

```
# subplot
plotly::subplot(
   # plot 1
   data %>% 
   ...
   plot_ly(
   ...
   ) %>%
   layout(
      xaxis = list(
        title = "xxx1",
        categoryorder = "total descending"
      )
   ),
   # plot 2
   data %>% 
   ...
   plot_ly(
   ...
   ) %>%
   layout(
      xaxis = list(
        title = "xxx2"
      )
   ),
   # plot 3
   ...,
   # plot 4
   ...,
   nrows = 4,
   shareX = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Can you make the category data a factor in the original dataset, and use the "plot1" data subset to establish the factor levels for all the subsets prior to plotting?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Actually I have no original dataset which I could use. I am joining several datasets and creating the variable that I would like to order each time separately in all 4 instances of the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Change the categories of the plot you want to control all else to a `factor` or `ordered` with the levels in the order you want them to appear.

```
library(plotly)

df1 <- data.frame(labs = letters[1:4],
                  vals = c(10, 20, 19, 8)) %>% 
  arrange(vals) %>% 
  mutate(labs = factor(labs, levels = .$labs))

df2 <- data.frame(labs = letters[1:4],
                  vals = c(10, 4, 3, 10))

df3 <- data.frame(labs = letters[1:4],
                  vals = c(20, 500, 3, 395))


p1 <- plot_ly(type = "bar", df1, x = ~labs, y = ~vals)
p2 <- plot_ly(type = "bar", df2, x = ~labs, y = ~vals)
p3 <- plot_ly(type = "bar", df1, x = ~labs, y = ~vals)

subplot(p1, p2, p3, shareX = T, nrows = 3)
```

[image]